# Nvidia Drivers Listed as Open Source

Tags: drivers, nvidia, open-source

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 Desktop, and when I list the available drivers to install, I see that there are a bunch of Nvidia drivers listed as open source (shown underlined in red below). I had come to understand that the Nvidia drivers are binary blobs that are not open source.

[image]

#### Question

Are there are open source Nvidia drivers or are they closed source binary blobs, and this interface needs fixing?

Comment: The interface needs fixing. This happens every time a PPA for graphics drivers is added. Not a problem but yes, the fix is due for many years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nouveau driver is open source. NVIDIA's own binary driver is not. It's a bug that they're displayed as being open source.

Comment: The bug: [LP: #1514057](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1514057)